# How can I find a file that was created within X minutes of a another file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm searching for a non-blank file (other than a header value) and want to find all other files created within 1 minute (or X minutes) of that file.

So far I have:

```
tail -n +2 `ls -rt *.csv | tail -n 1` > watch_me.txt
```

Which will trim off the first line of the last created csv file. If watch_me.txt is non-blank then I want to find all files that were created within 1 minute (or X minutes) of the csv file that I'm searching for.

Comment: Presumably some kind of Linux-based shell?  Please could you add some more-specific tags?

Comment: Will do!. I'm using bash on linux. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This command will find all files in the current directory that were modified withing 60 sec (+ or -) from modification time of file `watch_me.txt`

```
ts=$(stat --printf="%Y" watch_me.txt);
tsmin=$(date -d @$((ts-60)));
tsmax=$(date -d @$((ts+60))); 
find . -maxdepth 1 -newermt "$tsmin" -not -newermt "$tsmax"
```

Comment: On the system I'm using find doesn't allow the -newermt flag. I'm seeing if I can modify your script a little to grab what I want.

Comment: May be (and even simpler) you can just do `for f in $(find . -type f) ; do <here get stat of file and compare with tsmin and tsmax> ; done`

Answer (score 0):

Will a simple

```
ls -alt
```

i.e sort according to the files modification time suffice?
Then a `grep` using either `-A` or `-B` switch to extract
the matching lines after or before a matching file.